# Getting an error " 'JSON' is undefined " in webservices

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am new to webservice and JSON. I am developing an application in asp.net which uses Webservices and JSON for Posting data in Ajax call to Server.
In the below function PostData I am getting an error at:

```
 data: "{" + jsonObjectName + ":" + JSON.stringify(dataToSend) + "}",     as "json" is undefined.
```

Here dataToSend is an object which contains my data
submitType is submit button id (in page this I have two submit buttons so, I called by id)

strMessagetoShow is text to show success or failure
strMethodToCall which method is called in Webservice?

```
function PostData(dataToSend, submitType, strMessagetoShow, strMethodToCall,        jsonObjectName) {   
 $.ajax({
    url: window.top.GetWsUrl() + "/" + strMethodToCall,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{" + jsonObjectName + ":" + JSON.stringify(dataToSend) + "}",
    timeout: 30000,     
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        return data;
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: thank you @adeneo, i did that but still i am getting same error.

Comment: If it's quoted like in the question, it seems you have a problem with the quotes. Notice the colors in the question, and the data passed is no longer an object, it's something ... eh, well, else ?

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14101321/1577396)

Answer (score 1):

It's `JSON.stringify`, and `JSON.parse` with capital letters (javascript is case sensitive).

Also, when using a variable in an object, you have to do:

```
var obj = {};
    obj[jsonObjectName] = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);

$.ajax({
    ....
    data: obj,
    timeout: 30000,     
    ....etc
});
```

Comment: @RavinderGangadher - I'm just saying, any functions related to the JSON object in newer browsers requires you to referrence the correct object, which is JSON with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if helps:

```
function PostData(dataToSend, submitType, strMessagetoShow, strMethodToCall, jsonObjectName) {   
 $.ajax({
    url: window.top.GetWsUrl() + "/" + strMethodToCall,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {jsonObjectName : JSON.stringify(dataToSend)}, // or $.parseJSON(dataToSend)
    timeout: 30000,     
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        return data;
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
 });
}
```

What is changed here:

changed this :

```
  "{" + jsonObjectName + ":" + json.stringify(dataToSend) + "}"
```

to this:

```
 {jsonObjectName : JSON.stringify(dataToSend)}
```

Comment: Can you please mention as comments what you changed.. so that I can understand it..(I am with OP)

Comment: @Mr_Green - should be obvious, it's the data object. Now it's an object, in the question it's some sort of string with variables, which does'nt work.

Comment: @Mr_Green - in what browser ?

Comment: I have tested in IE, Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: And when using `JSON.stringify` Crome and Firefox says `JSON` is undefined if you open the console?

Comment: @adeneo The function is executing the **Error** function in Chrome and "json undefined" in IE9

Comment: @Mr_Green - Try keeping it simple, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sNmVE/1/), and open the console (F12) and check for errors !

Comment: @RavinderGangadher - The fiddle posted does'nt even use JSON, so that's simply not possible! The console should tell you exactly what line the error is on, are you sure it's not somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Just now i checked in console i am getting This errors.     1).Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined PalletizedWaste.aspx:162         
2).OPTIONS http://localhost:12015/WasteManagementWS.asmx/PalletizedWasteRecordExists 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery1.8.3.js:2
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:12015/WasteManagementWS.asmx/PalletizedWasteRecordExists. Origin http://localhost:51118 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @RavinderGangadher - since there are no attempts to read the id property of anything in the ajax function, that error probably lies elsewhere. The access-control error is Javascripts own origin policy, and you can't access a different domain with ajax, unless you're using JSONP or CORS.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you include the JSON library. See https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js for the API.

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
```